# android: sharedpreferences possible to use across activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i have created a sharedpreferences data in one activity, is it possible to be used in another activity? if yes, how could this be achieved?

The names of the 4 players are saved in NameIndex.java, and I would like to use the saved Names of the 4 players in the MainActivity.java

Under NameIndex.java:

```
   private void SaveNamesToFile(String Game1, String P1Name, String P2Name, String P3Name, String P4Name)
   // save the new row to the file, then refresh all Buttons
   {
      // originalScore will be null if we're modifying a slot that is existing already     
      String originalNameP1 = SavedNameP1.getString(Game1, null); // to return null if this preference does not exist. 
      String originalNameP2 = SavedNameP2.getString(Game1, null);
      String originalNameP3 = SavedNameP3.getString(Game1, null);
      String originalNameP4 = SavedNameP4.getString(Game1, null);

      // get a SharedPreferences.Editor to store new row data
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP1 = SavedNameP1.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP2 = SavedNameP2.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP3 = SavedNameP3.edit();
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditorP4 = SavedNameP4.edit();

      preferencesEditorP1.putString(Game1, P1Name);
      preferencesEditorP2.putString(Game1, P2Name);
      preferencesEditorP3.putString(Game1, P3Name);
      preferencesEditorP4.putString(Game1, P4Name);

      preferencesEditorP1.apply();
      preferencesEditorP2.apply();
      preferencesEditorP3.apply();
      preferencesEditorP4.apply();  
   }
```

Comment: what have you tried? using sharedpreference across one or several activity doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used one SharedPreferences file between activities, but what I did was using the same file name declared in different private variables inside the two activities. You can check my code in the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669707/load-sharedpreferences-in-mainactivity-and-update-in-an-secondary-activity). What I don't understand is why you use 4 SharedReferences files just for the names of the players and not all the names in just 1 file. That's possible because I used it to save more than 2 variables.

Comment: i have tried before that using one sharedpreference (SP), i.e. one key (slot#) for storing 4 variables (players' scores at that specific slot) but fails. It was because "The SharedPreferences solution works like a map. One VALUE to one KEY." I have asked such question also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438514/android-sharepreference. Maybe the coding can be modified further such that 1 SP using 1 key for 4 scores, but put it simple and not to be stucked i then defined 4 SP. Could you give some advise for that? All in all really many thanks for your suggestion~

Comment: @pearmak, I think you have 2 options:

- Use the string as an array of characters or as a plain text with indicators for each field if you want to keep using SharedPreferences. It's something I thought to do because it's true that the .putString function of the SharedPreferences Editor just work with 2 values: The name of the field you want to save and the value you want to store in it.

- If you want to access the data dinamycally like a database, then use the SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be shared across activities.  The easiest route is to just use:

```
context.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using it like this

```
     public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

        SharedPreferences myPrefs;
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

        private static SharedPreferencesHelper instance = null;

        public static synchronized SharedPreferencesHelper getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new SharedPreferencesHelper();
            }

            return instance;
        }



private SharedPreferencesHelper() {
myPrefs  = MyApplication.getInstanse().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    }

        public void putValueForKey(String key, String value) {
            prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }

    }


    public class MyApplication extends Application {

        private static MyApplication instance;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            instance = this; 
        }

        public static MyApplication getInstanse(){
            if(instance ==null){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Application not created yet!");
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```